# Simple PHP form doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php

I was trying to put a simple contact form on my site. I used a template I made on a earlier project, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working?

```
<?php


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];



$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$msg = strip_tags($msg);





$email_to = "my.email@email.com";
$email_subject = "Uusi yhteydenotto";

$email_message = "Uusi yhteydenotto: ";

$email_message = "\nName:" .$name.;

$email_message = "\nE-mail:" .$email.;

$email_message = "\n\nMessage:" .$msg.;






$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);




?>
```

I think this contains all the necessary things for it to work, but it doesn't seem to work? 
Keeps on giving me the error 500. The server should be PHP5 -approved so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: tell us the output of : `print_r(error_get_last());` and also the value of `var_dump(mail(...))`

Comment: @Matsutus Syntax errors in your code... Please check `.`

Comment: @matsutus please provide the html form too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$msg = strip_tags($msg);

$email_to = "my.email@email.com";
$email_subject = "Uusi yhteydenotto";

$email_message = "Uusi yhteydenotto: ";

$email_message .= "\nName:" .$name; /* removed .; */
$email_message .= "\nE-mail:" .$email; /* removed .; */
$email_message .= "\n\nMessage:" .$msg; /* removed .; */

/* change `$email_from` in $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".   */
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".  
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: May be missing $email_from. $email seems to be in use.

Comment: @BimalPoudel is right. $email_from is not declared. It will cause error too.

Comment: Hey thanks man! This fixed the issue! And also thanks for commenting what you changed :)

Answer (score 2):

should use concatenation operator `.`, your code should now look like below

```
$email_message = "Uusi yhteydenotto: ";

$email_message .= "\nName:" . $name;

$email_message .= "\nE-mail:" . $email;

$email_message .= "\n\nMessage:" . $msg;
```